# Compile file only if specific subdir changes with GNU Make

Tags: makefile

I have a set of files in a structure like this:

```
-src
   -SubDir1
     -file1.c
     -file2.h
    -file3.c
   -SubDir2
     -file1.c
    -file2.c
   -SubDir3
     -file1.c
    -file2.c
-outDir
```

I compile the files from each subdir with a script that generates a custom output file (.out). I have created a makefile that produces the .out file for each Subdir when any .c file changes in any subdir. The problem is that this will compile all the subdir, as I have created a rule that makes the .out files depend on all the .c files.

Is there a clever way to create a custom rule that makes each .out file only depend on the files of each subdir? Also the .out file should be in a new directory. Below you will find the makefile I have created

```
#Recursive wild card for all the subdirs
rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

SRCS_DIR=src
SRCS_SUBDIRS= $(wildcard $(SRCS_DIR)/*/)
FILES := $(call rwildcard,$(SRCS_DIR)/,*)

#Get each subdir name 
SUBDIRS_NAMES=$(subst $(SRCS_DIR)/,,$(SRCS_SUBDIRS)) 

#Output file has the name of each subdir with .out extension
OUTPUT_FILES=$(subst /,.out,$(SUBDIRS_NAMES))

Process_Outputs: $(OUTPUT_FILES)
    CustomProcess $@
    
/outDir/$(OUTPUT_FILES):$(FILES)
    myCustomScript $@
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(OUTPUT_FILES): %.out: src/%/file.c
    myCustomScript $@
```

Comment: is it possible to indicate more than one file?, i.e. a wildcard for .c files instead of just specifically `file.c`

Also could I modify the % value before its expanded? 
`$(OUTPUT_FILES):  %: $(substr from,to,%).c`

Comment: @Yudop: It would be very helpful to tell us what you're actually trying to do. If the example in your Question doesn't cover your real case, then edit it and I'll let someone else answer.